# Constancy of Coefficients of Additive Integrals Throughout Subsystems of a Closed System

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, integrals-of-motion

I'm studying Landau and Lifshitz's *Statistical Physics,* Part 1, 3rd edition and am looking for clarification on the following statement, which appears on page 11 in the section on The Significance of Energy:

> As we know from mechanics, there exist only seven independent additive integrals of motion: the energy, the three components of the momentum vector and the three components of the angular momentum vector. We shall denote these quantities for the *a*th subsystem (as functions of the coordinates and momenta of the particles in it) by $E_a$(p,q), $\mathbf{P}_a(p,q)$, $\mathbf{M}_a(p,q)$ respectively.

Landau/Lifshitz go on to say that since $\log{\rho_a}$ (that is, the distribution function for the $a$th subsystem) is an additive integral of the motion, it must be expressible as a linear combination:

$$\log{\rho_a} = \alpha_a + \beta E_a(p,q) + \mathbf{\gamma \cdot P}_a(p,q) + \mathbf{\delta \cdot M}_a(p,q)$$ 
"with constant coefficients $\alpha_a, \beta, \mathbf{\gamma}, \mathbf{\delta}$ of which $\beta, \mathbf{\gamma}, \mathbf{\delta}$ must be the same for all subsystems in a given closed system."

**I do not understand which assumptions were made to justify the statement that these coefficients must be the same for all subsystems.**

My best guess is that it follows from the assumption that the subsystems are weakly interacting in a sufficiently small time interval such that the distribution function of two subsystems together, $\rho_{12}$ is equal to the product of the distribution function of each subsystem ($\rho_1$, $\rho_2$) separately: 
$$\rho_{12} = \rho_1 \rho_2.$$

(Landau/Lifshitz call this "statistical independence" for sufficiently small times in "quasi-closed" subsystems.)

They also state that the closed system as a whole is in "statistical equilibrium," for which the time scales in question are long compared to the relaxation time. I don't know if this assumption is used to justify the claim about the coefficients or if it is in conflict with the time scale for which quasi-closed systems are statistically independent.

**It is not clear to me *how* the result follows from the weakly interacting or statistical equilibrium assumptions**, but the former is certainly required otherwise $\log{\rho_a}$ wouldn't be an *additive* integral and hence the linear combination wouldn't necessarily hold.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Also for clarity, I am willing to take for granted Landau/Lifshitz's claim that there exist only seven independent additive integrals of motion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the $a$ subsystem:

$$ \log \rho_a = \alpha_a + \beta_a E_a + \mathbf{\gamma}_a \cdot \mathbf{P}_a + \delta_a \cdot \mathbf{M}_a . $$

Writing down this equation assumes that Liouville's theorem is applicable, which itself assumes that the subsystem $a$ is closed (or quasi-closed for relatively short time intervals).

For another subsystem labelled $b$:

$$ \log \rho_b = \alpha_b + \beta_b E_b + \mathbf{\gamma}_b \cdot \mathbf{P}_b + \delta_b \cdot \mathbf{M}_b . $$

For the combined subsystem $ab$:

$$ \log \rho_{ab} = \alpha_{ab} + \beta_{ab} (E_{a} + E_{b}) + \mathbf{\gamma}_{ab} \cdot (\mathbf{P}_{a} + \mathbf{P}_{b}) + \delta_{ab} \cdot ( \mathbf{M}_{a} + \mathbf{M}_{b}) . $$

Substituting the three expressions above into the equation $\log \rho_{ab} = \log\rho_a + \log\rho_b$ (which follows from the "statistical independence" assumption) and equating the coefficients of the independent variables $E_a, E_b, \mathbf{P}_a, \mathbf{P}_b, \mathbf{M}_a, \mathbf{M}_b$ gives:

$$ \alpha_{ab} = \alpha_a + \alpha_b ,$$
$$ \beta_{ab} = \beta_a = \beta_b , $$
$$ \gamma_{ab} = \gamma_a = \gamma_b , $$
$$ \delta_{ab} = \delta_a = \delta_b . $$

So $\beta$, $\gamma$ and $\delta$ don't depend on the subsystem label.

Any closed macroscopic system will be in statistical equilibrium if it is observed for a long enough time (longer than the relaxation time), but I think that statistical equilibrium is an instantaneous quality of a system. Landau and Lifshitz' definition is:

> If a closed macroscopic system is in a state such that in any macroscopic subsystem the macroscopic physical quantities are to a high degree of accuracy equal to their mean values, the state is said to be in a state of statistical equilibrium.

So I think that a system can be both in statistical equilibrium and quasi-closed.